# C#, convert a database value to a string?

Tags: c#, database, windows, push

I have a report that gets updated every week that needs pushed out to 30+ PC's and the number is rising each week.  I am trying to figure out how to take an Access Database and push the files out from a location on our server to all of each of those PC's but what I can't wrap my head around is how to do it.  I was going to use a copy command and then use the value of the PC ID in a string and enter it into the file paths.  This is a little bit more advanced than I am used to working with. Here's what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet1.PCID_List' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.pCID_ListTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet1.PCID_List);

        }

        private void button_Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        static void button_Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string reportLocationCopy = @"Location TBD";
            string repLoc = @"Location TBD";
            if (File.Exists(repLoc))
            {
                // If file already exists in destination, delete it
                if (File.Exists(reportLocationCopy))
                    File.Delete(reportLocationCopy);
                File.Copy(repLoc, reportLocationCopy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is this:

Open a database connection that selects your required information. Then use a sqldata adapter/datatable to draw the number of rows. Then I would write a foreach statement that uses these PCs and sends the updated file. So off the top of my head...

```
 //select query here and your connectionstring
 //then fill table as seen below
 SqlDataAdapter sDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 sDA.Fill(table);

 foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
 {
    string pc = (row["PCs"].ToString());
     //send files
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be an option:
As the numbers of client PC are growing every week, why don`t you try writing web-service. It will provide the ease and central management. 
Now you have two case:

- If you are working on intranet, locally host your WCF service on IIS.
- If you have website then create web-service for that, then your internet based remote client can access your data.

You might need three things:

1. WCF service
2. IIS hosting
3. Client Application

Comment: I figured a small desktop application with an embedded Access database in a grid view that copies the updated file from a network drive and pastes it to each PC in the DB.  I just can't figure out how to use the DB's entries in strings in a copy command or if that's the way I should even be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Blue sky idea here, this may not be possible for security reasons. Can you push the database files to a Dropbox account, which the other machines also reference? This would provide quick synchronization of the machines as the database files are updated.

For what it's worth...

Answer (score 0):

If this is in an Enterprise, your sysadmins will have tools that can push to each PC.  I've done similar things to push application releases, and they can script whatever you need.

It might be worthwhile to post the question in a Sys Admin forum like serverfault or everythingsysadmin.

If your really dead set on managing the distribution, you can have your application call a Web Service or check a shared drive on startup for a newer version of the file and download it (either ftp or straight copy).

Let the client do the lookup to avoid issues like the PC not being available.  It also allows the client to cancel the load if they are in a hurry.  Nothings worse that having an update forced on you when you need something quickly!